# Add constraint to schema in Oracle Directory Server EE

Tags: oracle, ldap, constraints

Is there any way to add some constraint to LDAP schema in Oracle Directory Server Enterprice Edition? When I add my custom attribute using **Oracle Directory Server Control Server** I can define syntax of attribute from predefined list (like `INTEGER`, `Boolean` or `URI`). But I have some additional semantic rules. For example, I want to define `gender` attribute that can have only `F`,`M` or `U` value. Also it will be nice if I can define that `rating` attribute has type `Integer`, but `0<=rationg<=100`. Maybe there is some way to define my custom datatype like `rating` that can meet my semantic needs and is inherited from `INTEGER`?

**P.S.** I failed to find this particular abilities in administration guide and decided to post this question. Maybe solution is obvious - I am not an experienced `LDAP` administrator.

Answer (score 0):

To constrain the values of attributes the administrator must define attribute using a custom syntax. See also: [syntaxes and matching rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517).